# Trying to use .htaccess to redirect /profile to /login-2?action=profile

Tags: customization

I have a plugin [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) for WordPress 3.0.1 which causes my user's profile pages to be here: domain.com/login-2?action=profile

instead of here: domain.com/profile

So I am trying to fix it with mod_rewrite like this: RewriteRule ^profile /login-2?action=profile

But it seems to do nothing. I suspect it's some weird thing happening in WordPress but wanted to ask folks here if my rewrite rule looks correct before I dig further. Did I do it right?

Update: I had someone suggest I use wp_rewrite - which I noticed has some flush rules functions associated with it; perhaps wp is not noticing my changes to htaccess because a flush is needed first?

Comment: Yes, you should be using wp_rewrite because `/profile/` has already passed through `.htaccess` in order to point to the proper page ... you'll end up with strange conflicts if you try to override WP's rewrite engine manually through `.htaccess`.

Comment: I suggest like EAMann you keep the fingers of the .htaccess Rewrite Rules for a moment. In the event that something is wrong with the plugin you should contact that plugins support as well. Maybe those folks are already aware of a fix for your problem.

Comment: use the function wp_redirect() from WP for this and works great; i use this on different plugins, example is Adminimize with a rewrite after login and logout.
more in this post: http://wpengineer.com/1945/redirects-to-another-page-in-wordpress-backend/

Comment: Can you please link the plugin you're using? Probably what you describe is not an error at all and by intention, so all is totally okay and you just worry for nothing? Why fix something that isn't broken? And if it's broken, why not contact the plugin support?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been probably fixed in [version 6.0.4](http://www.jfarthing.com/blog/2010/11/15/theme-my-login-6-0-4/). Have you tried the latest version?